# Multi array JSON as string convert to array python

Tags: python, json

I need to process multiple JSON arrays as string and convert to a list in Python. Here is what I've tried:

```
array = '[{"drinks": ["coffee", "tea", "water"]}],' \
            '[{"drinks": ["coffee", "tea", "water"]}]'
data = json.loads(array)
print(data)
```

This generates the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
   "C:/Users/aessam/Desktop/sen/josnre.py", line 10, in <module>
       data = json.loads(array)   File "C:\Users\aessam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\json\__init__.py",
   line 319, in loads
       return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "C:\Users\aessam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\json\decoder.py",
   line 342, in decode
       raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end) json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 41 (char 40)
```

What's the problem, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array doesn't have `[]` around elements 
e.g. it is like this currently

```
array= '[], []'
```

instead of

```
array= '[[], []]'
```

Try this

```
array = '[[{"drinks": ["coffee", "tea", "water"]}],' \
            '[{"drinks": ["coffee", "tea", "water"]}]]'
data = json.loads(array)
print(data)
```